# ANTLR mixup between a token 'B' and the hexnumber 'B' without prefix

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I have difficulties finding a proper grammar for a language with the following structure:

```
W1234
B1234[16]
B6789
W6789,B
```

where 1234 and 6789 are any decimal number. And the ,B is any hex number without any prefix.

The grammar:

```
grammar Tsx7;

program returns [string code]
  : ident EOF
  ;

ident returns [string code]
    : 'W' NUMBER ( ',' ( DEC_DIGITS | HEX_DIGIT )+ )?
    | 'B' NUMBER ( '[' NUMBER ']' )?
    ;

NUMBER: DEC_DIGITS+;
fragment DEC_DIGITS: '0'..'9';
fragment HEX_DIGITS: 'A'..'F';
```

With these (legal) inputs

```
W1,B
W34,1
```

I get *InputMismatch* or *NoViableAlt* exception.

Where these inputs works without problems:

```
W1
B2[8]
B3123
```

I tried several grammars but couldn't find the correct one.

Thanks for any help, 
Martin

Answer (score 0):

Don't use lexer fragments in parser rules. They will never show up in the parser. Make those rules normal lexer rules or define one which calls the fragment rules.